Dynamo DB fetch data from paginated on one table and filter on another table
I have a use case where I have an Entity and it's resources. Entity and resources are stored in separate Dynamo DB table. User make API call to my entity and along that resources are also returned. But user can additionally apply filter in API call based on the attributes of the resource.
Now my problem is, when lets say user asks for 10 entity records, but if I apply filter on resources table, where the entity and resource relationship is one to many, then applying filter on resource table how I can apply pagination record count on entity table (or entity ID column of resource table)?


It may not be the answer you're looking for but I believe you have a badly designed data model.
With NoSQL databases and especially DynamoDB it's important that data that should be retrieved together should live together. You should de-normalise the data and store it in an efficient data model on a single table, which will align more accurately with your access patterns.



PK
SK




Entity1
Entity1


Entity1
Resource1


Entity1
Resource2



Or if it's many to many relationship then you can use the adjacency list pattern.

even lets say I de-normalize data, then also is there any way I can consolidate the data input? Any way you can suggest to design my table here? Because I need filtering on resource while pagination on entity, so in single table my entity data will be duplicated.

Updated my answer
